# Is asking about any trophy on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

If I want to know about any trophy e.g. What is XYZ trophy?, Why is XYZ trophy played? Which teams can participate on XYZ trophy? etc.

Are this type of questions on-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. With more effort, the following questions look on-topic to me:

- What is the Land Grant trophy?
- What is the Lombardi trophy?
- What is the Wanamaker trophy?
- What is the Stanley Cup?

Perhaps a tag for [trophy](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trophy) could be used, and it may be useful to add the [history](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag.

Comment: These can be easily found on the internet I guess?

Comment: I'm sure some are. Some are not so obvious. Hence "more effort" is required than just my examples above.